# Does getting a post graduate research TOPIC off the internet constitute plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism

I'm currently applying for a post graduate scholarship and need to do a research plan. I have an idea of what I would like to research on but i found a better coinage of the topic on the internet. Would it constitute plagiarism if I use this topic from the internet? its just the topic I need.
Would also appreciate any help on how to write a research plan.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to conduct a literature review, and it includes all the previous work that helped you come up with the idea and what you are going to add over the existing results.

If you cite the references of previous work, say clearly what they did and how your work is different (i.e. your work should add a new knowledge that is not known from previous work), then building on previous ideas is not a plagiarism.

If the idea is published but no one did the actual work, then, you must cite the source that provided the idea and say that no one did the work and you will do it.